# Why using crypt in glibc cause compiler warning?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings, glibc, crypt

I tried to compiler the following code(minimum example, see the edit for the whole code):

```
// a.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    puts((const char*) crypt("AAAA", "$6$2222"));
    return 0;
}
```

Using `clang-7 -lcrypt a.c` and it emitted the following warning:

```
minimum.c:8:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'crypt' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    puts((const char*) crypt("AAAA", "$6$2222"));
                       ^
minimum.c:8:10: warning: cast to 'const char *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    puts((const char*) crypt("AAAA", "$6$2222"));
         ^
2 warnings generated.
```

But `./a.out` did seem to work:

```
$6$2222$6GKY4KPtBqD9jAhwxIZGDqEShaBaw.pkyJxjvSlKmtygDXKQ2Q62CPY98MPIZbz2h6iMCgLTVEYplzp.naYLz1
```

I found out that if I remove `#include <stdio.h>` and `puts` like this:

```
// new_a.c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    crypt("AAAA", "$6$2222");
    return 0;
}
```

Then there is no warnings.

How to fix these warnings without removing `#include <stdio.h>`?

Edit:

Whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _X_OPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

#include <assert.h>

void* Calloc(size_t cnt, size_t size)
{
    void *ret = calloc(cnt, size);
    assert(ret);
    return ret;
}

size_t GetSaltLen(const char *salt)
{
    size_t salt_len = strlen(salt);
    assert(salt_len >  0);
    assert(salt_len <= 16);
    return salt_len;
}

char* GetSaltAndVersion(const char version, const char *salt)
{
    size_t saltlen = GetSaltLen(salt);
    /*
     * The format of salt:
     *     $one_digit_number$up_to_16_character\0
     * For more info, check man crypt.
     */
    char *ret = (char*) Calloc(1 + 1 + 1 + saltlen + 1, sizeof(char));

    char *beg = ret;

    *beg++ = '$';
    *beg++ = version;
    *beg++ = '$';
    memcpy((void*) beg, (const void*) salt, saltlen + 1);

    return ret;
}

void crypt_and_print(const char *passwd, const char *salt_and_version)
{
    char *result = crypt(passwd, salt_and_version);
    assert(puts(result) != EOF);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "argc = %d\n", argc);
        return 1;
    }

    char *salt_and_version = GetSaltAndVersion(argv[2][0], argv[3]);
    crypt_and_print(argv[1], salt_and_version);
    free(salt_and_version);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried as @Andrey Akhmetov suggested and put the `#define` onto the first line, but the warnings did not disappear.

Comment: You should specify a value `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` (for POSIX 2008, the current version) or 600 or 500 for older versions.  Specifying no value leads to quasi-indeterminate behaviour; the headers might treat that as 0, and it isn't clear which version of POSIX (X/Open) is identified by a version number of 0.

Comment: I `#define _X_OPEN_SOURCE 700` and it doesn't work on my original code.

Comment: You have a typo: It's `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and not `_X_OPEN_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is documented in [`feature_test_macros(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros). In particular, the manpage states:

> NOTE: In order to be effective, a feature test macro *must be defined before including any header files*. This can be done either in the compilation command (`cc -DMACRO=value`) or by defining the macro within the source code before including any headers.

When you include `stdio.h`, you indirectly include `features.h`, which uses the feature test macros as defined *at that point*. In particular, since `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and friends aren't defined at that point, `crypt.h` does not declare `crypt`.

By the time you define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` it is too late, since `features.h` has an include guard preventing it from being included twice.

By swapping the order of the first two lines, the code works without raising this warning on my system:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    puts((const char*) crypt("AAAA", "$6$2222"));
    return 0;
}
```

Your larger example does not work for a second reason: You wrote `_X_OPEN_SOURCE` as the name of the macro, while the correct name is `_XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to request a more modern standard by specifying `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` for example (500, 600, 700 are plausible values).

Comment: I've tried and this work on my minimum example, but don't work on the original code

Comment: @JiaHaoXu Please see edits; you have an extra underscore.